# Map multiple js files in requirejs

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I want to include yahoo.js and yahoo-calendar.min.js from my custom module

**yahoo.js**
[image]

**yahoo-calendar.min.js** 
[image]

basically i need to call the function from `yahoo-calendar.min.js` which require `yahoo.js` file, i tried to include it like this using `requirejs-config.js` from my custom module:

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            YAHOO: 'Vendor_Module::js/yahoo-calendar.min' 
        }
    }
};
```

i'm gonna use `YAHOO` as the alias , but i don't know where to put the `yahoo.js` file

the usage will be like this:

```
YAHOO.namespace("example.calendar");
                    YAHOO.example.calendar.init = function() {
                        YAHOO.example.calendar.cal1 = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("cal1",'container-id');
                        YAHOO.example.calendar.cal1.render();
                    }

                    YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(YAHOO.example.calendar.init);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple js files in your **requirejs-config.js** file. Try like below,

```
var config = {
    'map': {
        '*': {
            'yahoo' : 'Vendor_Module::js/yahoo', 
            'yahoo-calendar': 'Vendor_Module::js/yahoo-calendar.min' 
        }
    },
    'shim': {
        'yahoo-calendar': {
            deps: ['yahoo']
        }
    }
};
```

Here, `shim` is used to create a dependency with your JS files, It will make sure that your **yahoo.js** file will be called before it will call **yahoo-calendar.js**

One more thing to note here is that you do not add `.js` extension in your **requirejs-config.js** file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, in my main js , should i use the alias yahoo as YAHOO or yahoo-calendar as YAHOO ?

Comment: You can only use the file you require in your main.js, here, it is 'yahoo-calendar'

Comment: Allow your `main.js` to fetch dependencies dynamically. You need to wrap you function in **AMD: require()**  : 
`require(['yahoo-calendar'], function ( yahooCalendar ) {
        // rest of your code here
});`